# what's different between touch silde and mouse scroll in html5?

Tags: css, html, touch

Now I have a page, which markup is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
       many contents here, more than one page.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Currently, I can scroll the page both using **touch slide**(on my pad) and **mouse scroll**(on my pc):

But once I apply the following css:

```
#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

The page cannot be affected by **touch slide**, but still works good with **mouse scroll**. Why?

I want to make both scrolling ok with the second case, and curious to know what's the difference between **touch slide** and **mouse scroll**.

Plz help.

Comment: Why the `overflow: auto;`? This must cause you trouble with the `touchmove` event. If you remove this, does it work again?

Comment: @morkro oh, I missed one point, that I have a background which fits the `#main` size. So if I remove the `overflow: auto`, the part overflowing has no background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overflow:auto creates problem for touch device scrolling.
Try using overflow:hidden or overflow:scroll instead.